# Server slave, replication

Tags: mysql

I have a secondary server (slave), where it only receives replication from the Main. If I leave my.cnf settings like this: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 and SQL_LOG_BIN = 0 ; I miss something. Since I don't need the logbinary, because the slave is just a copy and I don't use it for other purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication requires several things to be set.

```
log_bin -- to say that replication is turned on
log_slave_updates  -- turn it on
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit -- not not directly relevant to replication
SQL_LOG_BIN  -- 0 says not to replicate subsequent writes in this connection
plus all that is set up by CHANGE MASTER
```

The intent of a Replica is to always have a full copy of the Primary.  Is that your goal?  Or maybe "take a snapshot of the Primary, but no keep it updated.

**Snapshot**

If you don't need the Replica to be kept up to date, then here are some idea on capturing an occasional snapshot:

- LVM -- best for least impact.
- `mysqldump` and use `mysql` to load on the target server -- straightforward, but invasive.
- Use replication even if you don't need the rest of the repl benefits.
- stop both servers; copy the disk over

Comment: yes,  a snapshot of the Primary.

Comment: @Leonardo - I added to my answer.